# Converting a JSON object to a formatted array via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, treeview

I have a JSON object that I would like to convert to an array so that I can use it with the [bootstrap-treeview](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) jQuery plugin. To do so, I need the JSON object to be in this format:

```
var tree = [
{
  text: "Parent 1",
  nodes: [
    {
      text: "Child 1",
      nodes: [
        {
          text: "Grandchild 1"
        },
        {
          text: "Grandchild 2"
        }
      ]
    },
  {
    text: "Child 2"
  }
]
},
{
  text: "Parent 2"
},
{
  text: "Parent 3"
},
{
  text: "Parent 4"
},
{
  text: "Parent 5"
}
];
```

I know that I probably need to recursively iterate over the JSON object but I don't know how.

Comment: Can you show me Json object format?

Comment: {"SectionsData":{".data.rel.ro":{"Characteristics":"","Entropy":1.55288},".jcr":{"Characteristics":"","Entropy":0}},"NumberOfSections":29,"SHA1":"7ED11BBA8EF27B8FE8617F5446142A3A0613CC41","Entropy":6.06652,"CodeSection":{"Characteristics":"","Entropy":6.19754}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var treeData = [];
var yourData = {
    "SectionsData": {
        ".data.rel.ro": {
            "Characteristics": "",
            "Entropy": 1.55288
        },
        ".jcr": {
            "Characteristics": "",
            "Entropy": 0
        }
    },
    "NumberOfSections": 29,
    "SHA1": "7ED11BBA8EF27B8‌​FE8617F5446142A3A0613CC41",
    "Entropy": 6.06652,
    "CodeSection": {
        "Characteristics": "",
        "Entropy": 6.19754
    }
};


function format(aSource, aTarget) {

    for (propertyName in aSource) {
        if (aSource.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && aSource[propertyName] instanceof Object) {
            var newNode = {text: propertyName, nodes: []};
            aTarget.push(newNode);
            format(aSource[propertyName], newNode.nodes);
        }
        else{
            aTarget.push({text: propertyName});
        }
    }
}

format(yourData, treeData);

console.log(treeData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help!

```
    arrConvert = new Array();
    function convertItem(p){
        arrItem = new Array();
        for (var key in p) {
              if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                  if($.type(p[key]) === "string" || $.type(p[key]) === "number" )
                      arrItem.push({"text":p[key]});
                  else{
                      arrItem.push({"nodes":convertItem(p[key])});
                  }
              }
        }
        return arrItem;
    }

    $(function(){
        var testArr = {
                        "SectionsData":[
                                    {"Characteristics":"abc", "Entropy":1.55288}, 
                                    {"Characteristics":"xyz",   "Entropy":1.55288},
                                    {"Characteristics":"mno", "Entropy":1.55288}
                                ],
                        "NumberOfSections":29,
                        "SHA1":"7ED11BBA8EF27B8‌​FE8617F5446142A3A0613CC41",
                        "Entropy":6.06652,
                        "CodeSection":[
                                        {"Characteristics":"abc1", "Entropy":1.55288}, 
                                        {"Characteristics":"xyz2",  "Entropy":1.55288},
                                        {"Characteristics":"mno3", "Entropy":1.55288}
                                    ]        
                        };

        //This is array after convert
        arrConvert = convertItem(testArr);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(i in tree) {
  console.log(tree[i].text);  //print "Parent 1 to 5"
}
```

ref: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: I don't need to print the parents, I need to take a json object and convert it to this format.